# My Cookie is not set correctly

Tags: php, cookies

i have problem with my Cookie setting this is the line of code:

```
if(!empty($userdata)) {

    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM st_user WHERE oid = '$uid'");
    $get_array = mysql_fetch_array($qry);

    $set_id_session = md5($username);
    //And then set cookies
    setcookie('FBSESSID', '$set_id_session', time()+86400, '/', '.setujuh.com'); //Cookie set at this line

    $do_sess = $_COOKIE['FBSESSID'];

    echo $_COOKIE['FBSESSID'];
    print_r($_COOKIE);

    $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

    mysql_query ("UPDATE st_user SET fb_sess_id = '$do_sess', lastvisitDate = '$date' WHERE oid = '$uid'");

}
```

my Question is why my Cookie is not set when i try to call it?

Comment: Where does `$username` come from?

Comment: $username is get from my database.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do `$get_array['username']` then?

Comment: it can be from $username = $fetch['u_name'];

Comment: but if i try to echo $username, it showing.

Comment: any solution for this case?

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Try `var_dump(set_cookie(setcookie('FBSESSID', $set_id_session, time()+86400, '/', '.setujuh.com'));` If true, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what username contains. Otherwise it will be NULL

```
 $username = $get_array['username']
```

Assuming $userdata is not empty, because otherwise the sql query will never be executed

**UPDATE**

It is a really bad idea to call md5($username) as a session id, because this id will be the same every time you login and you can impersonate another account if you know the username

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes around `$set_id_session`. For starters it's unnecessary, since it's already a string, but more importantly variables are only interpolated if you use double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I picked up a secure randomness generator, which should be perfect for your cookie verification token (Session ID);

```
    function TokenGenerator($Length)
    {
        $CharPool = '0123456789';
        $CharPool .= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        $CharPool .= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        $RandomNumber = function($Minimum, $Maximum) 
        {           
            # Find the range of the maximum and minimum allowed output
            $Range = $Maximum - $Minimum;

            # If the range is less than 0 forget the rest and return the minimum allowed number as  a 'random' bit
            if($Range < 0) 
            {
                return $Minimum; 
            }

            # Calculate the logarithm for $Range variable
            $Logarithm = (int) log($Range, 2)+1;

            $ByteLength = (int) ($Logarithm-1/8)+1;

            $BitF = (int) (1 << $Logarithm)-1; 

            do 
            {   
                # Get some random binary bytes
                $RndBinBytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ByteLength);

                # Converts the binary to hexadecimal
                $HexBytes = bin2hex($RndBinBytes);

                # Convert the hexadecimal bytes to decimal
                $Random = hexdec($HexBytes);

                # Use the AND operator to discard the unneeded bits
                $Random = $Random & $BitF; 
            } 
            while($Random >= $Range);

            # Return the random number found by the sub function to the main function
            return $Minimum + $Random;
        };

        # Initialise the RandChars variable
        $RandChars = '';

        $LengthOfPool = strlen($CharPool);

        for ($Counter = 0; $Counter < $Length; $Counter +=1) 
        {
            $RandNum = $RandomNumber(0, $LengthOfPool);

            # Pick from the pool of chars
            $RandChar = $CharPool[$RandNum];

            # Append the random char to the token to be returned at the end
            $RandChars .= $RandChar;
        }
        return $RandChars;
    }
```

To add another layer of security to your cookie plan you could encrypt the contents of the cookie to ensure the cookie isn't tampered with in the first place, when I set cookies I use this class;

```
    class CookieMonster
    {
        private $CookieKey = 'SecurePassword';

        public function SetCookie($Name, $Data, $Expire=31536000)
        {
            if($Data == '')
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            if($Name == '')
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            if($Key == '')
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            return setcookie($Name, $this->Encrypt($Data, $this->CookieKey), $Expire);
        }

        public function DeleteCookie($Name)
        {   
            if(isset($_COOKIE[$Name]))
            {
                return setcookie($Name, '', 1);
            }
        }

        public function ReadCookie($Name)
        {
            if(isset($_COOKIE[$Name]))
            {
                return $this->Decrypt($_COOKIE[$Name], $this->CookieKey);
            }else{
                return FALSE;   
            }
        }

        public function Encrypt($Data, $Key)
        {
            return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, sha1($Key), $Data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(sha1($Key))));
        }

        public function Decrypt($Data, $Key)
        {
            return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, sha1($Key), base64_decode($Data), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(sha1($Key))), "\0");
        }   
    }
```